# Adding members to security group: SetInfo returns error 80070005

Tags: vbscript, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

**Background**
I working on (modifying) a vbscript intended to create an AD shadow group formed by all users of several OU's.
The script logs into a remote AD, using [alternate credentials](http://www.rlmueller.net/ADOAltCredentials.htm).
***Note:** The user I log in as, have full AD read access, but only inherited write access to the OU containing the group I'm adding members to.*

**Problematic code**
The script is easily able to log in, scan for users on the OU's, open the shadow group and list it's current members, perform compares and locate the users to add and remove....but...
the actual adding (and removing) of members to the named security group fails, `Error: 80070005  Srce: Active Directory  Desc: Access is denied.`, when I apply `.SetInfo`.

I'm using this code to read and write:

```
aMembers = oGroup.GetEx("member") ' This gets populated as it should.

oGroup.PutEx ADS_PROPERTY_APPEND, "member", Array("CN=Doe\, John [LOCATION/COUNTRY],OU=foo,OU=bar,OU=Country,DC=domain,DC=org")
oGroup.SetInfo ' This fails
```

Just in case this is related to how I log into the AD, here's the code:

```
' Open an ADO connection using full credentials
Set oConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
oConnection.Properties("User ID") = sLDAP_USER   ' "domain\user"
oConnection.Properties("Password") = sLDAP_PASS  ' "pass!word"
oConnection.Properties("Encrypt Password") = True
oConnection.Properties("ADSI Flag") = ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION Or ADS_SERVER_BIND
oConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
```

**Verifying my login users rights**
I've seen lots of similar posts with this sort of error, and have only seen answers stating that this is a permission problem - however never seen a description of what permission was missing/wrong. The `Access is denied` error really made me doubt that the login I used had the right permissions, so I attempted to add members to the group by using [JXplore](http://jxplorer.org/). It works, but only if I enable the option to `ignore schema checking` (Based on online advice, when using JXplore with AD instead of pure LDAP). 

*Edit: Without ignoring the schema checking, the following properties are also requested to be populated: instanceType, nTSecurityDescriptor and objectCatagory, but I notice they are blank on existing users.*

**Questions**

1. Did I fall into an obvious pitfall?
2. Do I also somehow need to ignore the schema in my script? If so, how to do that?

Comment: Can you try using an account that you KNOW has Full Control permissions to the OU (i.e. your network admin account if you have one) with your script and see if you get the same error? I'd have to say this looks like a permissions issue as you mentioned. If your admin account works, you know that it isn't the script and you need to look at the service account's permissions.

Comment: @Sylverac I'll see if I can persuade  the IT department to test the script.  Good suggestion!

Comment: I ended up making a powershell solution, which is published here: http://fsteff.blogspot.com/2015/10/adldap-user-directories-setup-in.html